# How do I prevent an event from triggering during a GSAP animation?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, gsap

I have a GSAP animation like this:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', ()=>{
     GSAP.to(this.box, {
     x: this.box.position.x + 4,
     duration: 1,
    }
});
```

I want to increment the box's `x` position by multiples of 4, and my current code above works, but only if the user waits until 1 second has passed before pressing another key. Then it goes `0 -> 4 -> 8` etc.

If they don't wait a second, what happens is something like `0 -> 3.76 -> 6.45`. These numbers change depending on how long a user waits before they press another key. This makes sense because I'm effectively cancelling the animation and using the current position (since 1 second hasn't passed yet, it wouldn't get to 4 yet) and then just rerunning the animation with the current position (that wasn't 4).

Essentially, I want to prevent the 'keydown' event listener from triggered until the 1 second animation has been fully completed.

How would I do that?

Comment: Why not create a variable that is used to determine whether you want to run the code in the event?

Comment: @LeeTaylor Thanks for the suggestion - I just gave it a try, do you mean something like that (updated my post)? it works better, but if a user holds down the key it still cancels the animation earlier

Comment: It's hard to see without a fully working demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```js
class Test {
  constructor(el) {
    this.box = el

    window.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
      if (!this.tl || !this.tl.isActive()) {
        this.tl = gsap.to(this.box, {
          x: "+=4",
          duration: 1,
        })
        console.log("Moving to:", Math.floor(this.box.getBoundingClientRect().x))
      }
    });
  }
}

const test = new Test(box)
```

```css
#box {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.10.4/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.10.4/CSSRulePlugin.min.js"></script>
```

Probably not the cleanest solution, gsap is a great tool and surely has some better way to handle this scenario, but this is the first *brutal* approach that came to my mind.

EDIT:
Using `isActive()` method is already a tiny bit better.